# Use RelayCommand of my ViewModel in another Class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently making a FileExplorer in C# WPF. My ViewModel loads up the directories of the Sidebar and the Directories of the main field of the explorer. I tried to make it look like the Windows File Explorer.
So let's say the application is starting at C:\users\myname. My application loads all the directories in this path and displays it as buttons. Now once I click on the button, I want to move to the directory I'm clicking on.

Example: C:\users\myname -> C:\users\myname\desktop
The path is linked to the Button and given as Command Parameter, but I can't access the button, as the ItemSource is a List inside my ViewModel and not the ViewModel itself.
So the compiler tells me it can't find the RelayCommand, because it's not part of NavigationDirectory.cs

NavigationDirectory.cs:

```
   public class NavigationDirectory
    {
        public NavigationDirectory(string directoryName, DateTime creationTime, DateTime changeTime, string path)
        {
            DirectoryName = directoryName;
            CreationTime = creationTime;
            ChangeTime = changeTime;
            Path = path;
        }

        public string DirectoryName { get; set; }

        public string Path { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime ChangeTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Command in my ViewModel I'm trying to access:

```
 public RelayCommand MainDirectoryLoad { get; set; }

 public MainViewModel()
        {
            LoadMainDirectory();
            MainDirectoryLoad = new RelayCommand(o => LoadMainDirectory());
        }
 public void LoadMainDirectory(string path = @"C:\Users\renes\")
        {
            NavigationPath = path;
            MainDirectory = new List<NavigationDirectory>();
            var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(NavigationPath);
            foreach (string file in directories)
            {
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(file);
                SidebarDirectory = new NavigationDirectory(
                    dirInfo.Name,
                    dirInfo.CreationTime,
                    dirInfo.LastWriteTime,
                    dirInfo.FullName);
                MainDirectory.Add(SidebarDirectory);
            }
        }
```

The ListBox in my .xaml I want to use the Command in:

```
     <ListBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding MainDirectory}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button  Width="150" Height="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource NavigationButton}"
                             Command="{Binding MainDirectoryLoading}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/Images/icons/folder.png" Margin="5"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DirectoryName}" Style="{StaticResource NavigationTextBlock}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}" Style="{StaticResource NavigationTextBlock}" FontSize="10" Foreground="Gray"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChangeTime}" Style="{StaticResource NavigationTextBlock}" FontSize="8" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Is there any way on how to use the RelayCommand of my MainViewModel inside my NavigationDirectory Class or is there a way of passing the Command in the xaml, even though the ItemSource is not the MainViewModel?

**If not, then what's a good way to solve this issue?** Making a new Command in my NavigationDirectory would mean that I would have to pass parameters like the NavigationPath into it aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind to a property of a visual ancestor using a `{RelativeSource}`:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.MainDirectoryLoad, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
```

Make sure that the name of the properties match. In the XAML you have posted, you try to bind to some `MainDirectoryLoading` property but the property in your code seems to be called `MainDirectoryLoad`.

Comment: Oh yes the one I was calling was a leftover from trying things. I will try your idea and see if it works, thanks!